# Symfony dynamic pages with twig

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

I'm just starting my journey with Symfony, and single pages are working great. I've used Twig with OpenCart so I have some understanding of the syntax.

Following https://symfony.com/doc/5.2/setup.html has been a huge help.

My question is, how do I use twig inheritance properly for dynamic pages? (anon, authenticated, certain roles) how do I populate the base twig file with the stylesheets and javascripts when I'm calling:

```
    public function number(int $max): Response {
        $number = random_int(0, $max);

        return $this->render('lucky/number.html.twig', [
                    'number' => $number,
        ]);
    }
```

**base.html.twig**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

**number.html.twig**

```
{# templates/lucky/number.html.twig #}
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Blog</h1>

    <h1>Your lucky number is {{ number }}</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the down vote with no explanation. Symfony has so many awesome modules, I figured there would have to be a built in way of using templates for the whole site.

Comment: So what I was looking for was theme support. I haven't tried any yet but SyliusThemeBundle and  LiipThemeBundle look promising.

Answer (score -1):

You just do it the same way that you are populating the body block

```
{% block javascripts %}
{{ parent() }} {# call parent for any common js #}
{# your <script tags> #}
{% endblock %}
```

In your `base.html.twig` put any js or stylesheet that is common to all of your pages.

Comment: Thanks, but not quite what I was after. Each controller doesn't know what needs to go into the base template file. Turns out it was Themes is the word I should have put in. I found a couple bundles, but they look a bit bulky. But I'll play around and see how they go.